# Java Generic Function Return Type

Tags: java, generics

I want to create a collection of actions for specified class types. I was attempting something as follows.

```
Map<Class<?>, Function<String, ?>> mapper = new HashMap<>();
```

I end up populating this as

```
mapper.add(MyClass.class, s -> someMethod(s));
```

and the usage then looks like

```
mapper.get(MyClass.class).apply("someString");
```

This is all good, But I also want to force the return type of `Function` to match the key for the `mapper`. That is have the `mapper` defined as

```
Map<Class<T>, Function<String, T>> mapper = new HashMap<>();
```

The objective is that `mapper` should only be populated with functions which return an object of the type specified by the key. In effect, I want to make sure that

```
mapper.get(MyClass.class).apply("someString");
```

returns an object of the type `MyClass`. However using the `T` instead of the wildcard does not appear to work. I get a compiler error. Is this even possible in Java or I am kidding myself and should stick to the wild card approach?

Comment: Can you provide an example what you're looking for?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the link. So my problem went away using the approach specified in the linked question. I just added a method `<R> R mapStr(<Class<R> clazz, String str) { return clazz.cast(MAPPER.get(clazz).apply(str));}`

Comment: Actually, the problem isn't exactly solved with the linked approach. My objective was to stop the `mapper` from being populated with functions which return a type other than the one specified in the key.